# Write-behind caching solution for Java objects, using oracle stored procs for persistence

Tags: java, stored-procedures, persistence

Im currently working on a high throughput, low latency transaction engine. For audit reasons I need to maintain object state both locally, and also persist it to DB (Oracle).

Our DBAs insist that raw SQL is not allowed, so we use stored procedures to read/write data to the database.

I've looked around, but cannot find any obvious solution.

Is there anything out there that will act as a write-behind cache (for performance) that will allow me to specify (on a per class basis) the code that is used to persist/retreive objects (so I can inject the sproc handling code)?

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past in this situation is to write the data to [Java Chronicle](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle) and have this forwarded to a database in another thread or process. Java Chronicle supports low latency persisted IPC.  You can persist objects at a rate of over one million per second with sub-micro-second latencies.  The reading process can pick up those objects/events with in 100 nano-seconds.  As you have to do the JDBC part yourself, you do this any manner you choose.

Comment: Interesting. Does chronicle have any kind of notification mechanism, to allow a background thread to be notified of a new local persisted/updated object that needs to be stored in the DB?

Comment: @PaulJWilliams You can add one with LockSupport park() and unpark() but typically you would poll for changes on the reader, batch up the changes in a transaction and commit when there is nothing more, fall asleep for 10 ms to 1 seconds, try again.  This allows the batch size to grow with the work load.